# Laravel 4 database.php can't access DB

Tags: php, mysql, svn, laravel, laravel-4

I have a `laravel4` app working on my work computer. I recentley download the files via `svn` onto my home machine and when I attempt to open the project in the browser I get the following error:

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (View: C:\wamp\www\xzy.tld\app\views\layout.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\xyz.tld\app\views\layout.blade.php)
```

This is my `database.php` file:

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'xyz',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

I know for a fact that my home machine does not require a password for `mysql` so I don't know why this is happening? Is there some sort of `composer` command I should run in order to update my project?

EDIT: Strangely if I navigate to the `Connector.php` class within the framework and `var_dump` the `$config` variable I get this:

```
array (size=9)
  'driver' => string 'mysql' (length=5)
  'host' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'database' => string 'xyz' (length=10)
  'username' => string 'root' (length=4)
  'password' => string 'root' (length=4)
  'charset' => string 'utf8' (length=4)
  'collation' => string 'utf8_unicode_ci' (length=15)
  'prefix' => string '' (length=0)
  'name' => string 'mysql' (length=5)
```

I don't know where this information is coming from because in my `database.php` file I have password set to nothing. If I delete all contents of the `database.php` file I still get same error.

Comment: did you add your machine's hostname to the appropriate environment?

Comment: The hostname is localhost. If you see my edit above

Comment: Questions that come to mind... what database config are you modifying? /config/local/database.php or /config/database.php? Not sure if it'll help, but have you tried `php artisan cache:clear`? It sometimes helps me when I'm experiencing unexplained issues.

Comment: I was in fact editing the local file. I'll accept that as answer if you want to answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're reading from the wrong configuration file. Check the credentials in both

```
app/config/local/database.php
```

and

```
app/local/database.php
```

It may be whatever means you'r to identify the local environment on one machine don't work on the second machine, and Laravel's reading from different files.